# Check for null keys in map? Presto

Tags: sql, dictionary, presto

I have a query that was running fine for a while now that was doing the following:

```
  MAP_AGG(key, value(which is a map))
      AS k_v1,
  MAP_CONCAT(
      k_v(some map),
      MAP_UNION_SUM(
          MAP(ARRAY[K], ARRAY[V])
      ) as k_v2
```

With some data from source that looks like this:

| key | value | k_v | K | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_2 | {"KEY2": "20"} | {"KEY4": "100"} | KEY8 | 100 |
| id_1 | {"KEY1": "96.25"} | {"KEY5": "150"} | KEY8 | 150 |

In which it provides a table as such:

| k_v1 | k_v2 |
| --- | --- |
| {"id_2":{{"KEY2": "20"}, "id_1":{"KEY1": "96.25"}} | {{"KEY4": "100"}, {"KEY5": "150"}, {"KEY8": "250"}} |

But now as a new job was running, I get an error stating that

> "Failure": "map key cannot be null"

I'm trying to understand how to catch such a case with Presto, as it seems pretty verbose of a process to have to unnest these kinds of situations to check for null keys. Is there a more easier or built in solution to do this kind of check and remove that from the mapping?

Edit: I have hundred's of thousands of records that needs to be processed. The sample data above is to illustrate the schema.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure were and how you want to apply `unnest` but my guess would be that source of issue is `MAP(ARRAY[K], ARRAY[V])` with some of `K` being `null` (`MAP_AGG` should ignore null keys and other methods are working with existing maps). For this case you can try using conditional expression to ignore such rows (by creating empty maps) - `if(K is null, MAP(), MAP(ARRAY[K], ARRAY[V]))`:

```sql
MAP_CONCAT(
  k_v(some map),
  MAP_UNION_SUM(
      if(K is null, MAP(), MAP(ARRAY[K], ARRAY[V]))
  ) as k_v2
```

or substitute value with some default with `coalesce(K, 'KEYDEFAULT')`:

```sql
MAP_CONCAT(
  k_v(some map),
  MAP_UNION_SUM(
      MAP(ARRAY[coalesce(K, 'KEYDEFAULT')], ARRAY[V])
  ) as k
```